# Running react E2E test with nightwatch in env 'phantomjs' with error

Tags: reactjs, phantomjs, nightwatch.js

It seems the react page wasn't render in phantomjs env, but it works in chrome env.

After check the 'selenium-debug.log' file, I found the information as below:

```
18:20:27.889 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities   [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=true, phantomjs.page.setting.userAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36, phantomjs.cli.args=[--debug=true], databaseEnabled=true, platform=ANY, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, phantomjs.binary.path=C:\Work\CGC\IAM\source\example-portal\front-end\node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt\lib\phantom\bin\phantomjs.exe, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, name=Components\ Login Component Spec, browserName=phantomjs, javascriptEnabled=true}]]
18:20:27.949 INFO - Executing: [get: http://localhost:8080/])
[ERROR - 2017-02-16T10:20:28.407Z] Session [896dad20-f431-11e6-be45-67612b4b3938] - page.onError - msg: TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'Object.assign({},{userReducer:i.default,routing:n.routerReducer})')

phantomjs://platform/console++.js:263 in error
[ERROR - 2017-02-16T10:20:28.407Z] Session [896dad20-f431-11e6-be45-67612b4b3938] - page.onError - stack:
(anonymous function) (http://localhost:8080/app-c71287b53febd6a0d94c.js:28)
(anonymous function) (http://localhost:8080/app-c71287b53febd6a0d94c.js:28)
(anonymous function) (http://localhost:8080/app-c71287b53febd6a0d94c.js:28)
r (http://localhost:8080/vendor-c71287b53febd6a0d94c.js:1)
(anonymous function) (http://localhost:8080/app-c71287b53febd6a0d94c.js:29)
(anonymous function) (http://localhost:8080/app-c71287b53febd6a0d94c.js:29)
r (http://localhost:8080/vendor-c71287b53febd6a0d94c.js:1)
(anonymous function) (http://localhost:8080/app-c71287b53febd6a0d94c.js:40)
(anonymous function) (http://localhost:8080/app-c71287b53febd6a0d94c.js:40)
r (http://localhost:8080/vendor-c71287b53febd6a0d94c.js:1)
webpackJsonp (http://localhost:8080/vendor-c71287b53febd6a0d94c.js:1)

phantomjs://platform/console++.js:263 in error
18:20:28.428 INFO - Done: [get: http://localhost:8080/]
```

my nightwatch.config.js

```
{
  'src_folders': ['test/e2e/specs'],
  'output_folder': 'test/e2e/reports',
  'custom_commands_path': ['node_modules/nightwatch-helpers/commands'],
  'custom_assertions_path': ['node_modules/nightwatch-helpers/assertions'],

  'selenium': {
    'start_process': true,
    'server_path': require('selenium-server').path,
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'port': 4444,
    'cli_args': {
      'webdriver.chrome.driver': require('chromedriver').path,
    }
  },

  'test_settings': {
    'default': {
      'launch_url' : 'http://localhost:8080',
      'selenium_port': 4444,
      'selenium_host': 'localhost',
      'silent': true,
      'screenshots': {
        'enabled': true,
        'on_failure': true,
        'on_error': false,
        'path': 'test/e2e/screenshots'
      }
    },

    'chrome': {
      'desiredCapabilities': {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'javascriptEnabled': true,
        'acceptSslCerts': true,
        'chromeOptions' : {
          'args' : ['--none']
        }
      }
    },

    'firefox': {
      'desiredCapabilities': {
        'browserName': 'firefox',
        'javascriptEnabled': true,
        'acceptSslCerts': true,
        'marionette': true
      }
    },

    'phantomjs': {
      'desiredCapabilities': {
        'browserName': 'phantomjs',
        'javascriptEnabled': true,
        'acceptSslCerts': true,
        'databaseEnabled': true,
        'locationContextEnabled': true,
        'applicationCacheEnabled': true,
        'browserConnectionEnabled': true,
        'webStorageEnabled': true,
        'rotatable': true,
        'nativeEvents': true,
        "phantomjs.cli.args" : ['--debug=true'],
        'phantomjs.binary.path' : require('phantomjs-prebuilt').path,
        'phantomjs.page.setting.userAgent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Read about the bug for all the other people running into a similar issue here: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14257 .. sounds like it could be a number of issues.  Will require some trial and error by you to resolve it. Personally, if you can, use xvfb instead do that -- http://elementalselenium.com/tips/38-headless

Comment: @Clay thanks, i'm using the Xvfb for the test, and it works, thanks again.